# How i can use absolute path in k6 load testing framework

Tags: javascript, k6

I want to use absolute path in k6 js script file. Can someone please help in how to do this?

Instead of this

```
import {getAddCookieInfoPayLoad} from "../../../scripts/oAuth/addCookieInfoScript.js";
import {getQueryCookieInfoPayLoad} from "../../../scripts/oAuth/queryCookieInfoScript.js";
```

I want this:

```
import {getAddCookieInfoPayLoad} from "scripts/oAuth/addCookieInfoScript.js";

import {getQueryCookieInfoPayLoad} from "scripts/oAuth/queryCookieInfoScript.js";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute paths:

```js
import {getAddCookieInfoPayLoad} from "/absolute/path/to/scripts/oAuth/addCookieInfoScript.js";
```

and you can also import them with the `file://` schema:

```js
import {getAddCookieInfoPayLoad} from "file:///absolute/path/to/scripts/oAuth/addCookieInfoScript.js";
```

Though in general I find relative paths to be more usable and be more reliable when multiple people are working on the scripts, possibly across different OSes.

Comment: I want something like this for my custom import scripts.    import http from "k6/http";